# C++ in Netbeans: many senseless "unexpected token" hints

Tags: c++, netbeans, token, hints

I am very new to coding C++ and to using the Netbeans IDE. Worse yet, I'm on a Mac (but I can't imagine that's the source of the issue this time).

The IDE is giving me countless nonsense "hints" as in red exclamation mark symbols, most of which say "Unexpected token" for things like ';' at the end of a statement or '=' in a statement. These are of course ridiculous because, as I understand c++ so far, they are necessary for even the most basic statements!
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRAsn.png)
What could possibly be causing this and how do I get rid of the hints or, preferably, fix something if there is an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Delete your Netbeans cache. In my case the problem when away when I did this. I think I initially ended up in this state because my C++ project was under a Java project. After separating the two the error was still present even with a clean/build. Deleting the Netbeans cache got rid of the problem. Even if your situation is different you should try this. Clearing the Netbeans cache once in a while fixes a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler,
     I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you've got your Net beans ide setup to use another language other than C++. Remake the project and make sure your using c++

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The issue was, I wrote `C++14` code, in the `C++` project.

To resolve this:
- Create a `C++14` project (Select from the drop down, while creating the project)
- Add existing C++ files to it

Hope that helps.